# Bulk inserting data with XML format file in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I am pretty new to databases (normally stored everything locally on CSV or HDFS files). I have access to MS SQL Server and I have been trying to load some historical data into the database. I was successful finally and I want to redo my steps for other data, but first I want to make sure that I am being efficient.

1) I create a table using a query and specify the data type of each column and the number of characters (I used len() in Excel and then added a buffer just in case)

2) I then created an XML file, example is below. I notated the delimiter and the data type for each column along with things like max_length and precision/scale where needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
    <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="10"/>
    <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="3"/>
    <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="3"/>
    <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="18" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="19" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="20" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="21" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="22" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="23" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="24" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="25" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="26" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="27" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="28" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="29" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="30" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="31" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="32" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="33" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="34" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="35" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="36" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="37" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="38" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="39" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="40" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
    <FIELD ID="41" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n"/>
 </RECORD>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="date" xsi:type="SQLDATE"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="time" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="other_date" xsi:type="SQLDATE"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="other_time" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="client_id" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="location_id" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="other_id" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="stuff_1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="stuff_2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="email" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="something_active" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="something_active" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="etc" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="etc2" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="18" SCALE="2"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="filler" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="filler" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="17" NAME="fk1" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="18" NAME="fk2" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="19" NAME="fk3" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="20" NAME="fk4" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="21" NAME="fk5" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="22" NAME="fk6" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="23" NAME="fk7" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="24" NAME="data1" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="25" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="26" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="27" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="28" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="29" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="30" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="31" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="32" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="33" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="34" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="35" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="36" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="5" SCALE="2"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="37" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="38" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="39" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="40" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="5" SCALE="0"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="41" NAME="data" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

This worked and it was pretty fast for a few million rows. My question now is whether I need to do this for each file I am going to import (each is probably around 1 million to about 20 million records)? It is somewhat tedious creating a separate CREATE TABLE query and XML file per file, but it should only be a one time thing. Just want to make sure that I am not missing out on a more efficient approach to this whole thing.

Comment: If your files share the same layout, you can use the same format file.

Comment: No luck there. Each file is different with different column names and data types. I am copying the old one and just editing it row per row though. Is my general approach correct? This is my first attempt in loading data into a database ever.